# webapp2 DomainRoute with multiple Route

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

I got a problem with URI Route.

```
http://www.example.com - OK  
http://www.example.com/en - 404  
http://www.example.com/bm - 404  
http://www.example.com/my - 404  
http://www.example.com/zh - 404  
http://www.example.com/cn - 404
```

It look like ignored my second Route onward, what is wrong with my route?

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
routes.DomainRoute(r'<:(localhost|example\.com|www\.example\.com)>', [
  webapp2.Route('/', handler=WebHome, name='WebHome'),
  webapp2.Route('/(en|bm|my|cn|zh)', handler=WebHome, name='WebHome'),
  webapp2.Route('/(en|bm|my|cn|zh)/', handler=WebHome, name='WebHome'),
]),

routes.DomainRoute(r'<:(m2.example.com|m.example.com)>', [
  webapp2.Route('/', handler=MobileHome, name='MobileHome'),
  webapp2.Route('/(en|bm|my|cn|zh)', handler=MobileHome, name='MobileHome'),
  webapp2.Route('/(en|bm|my|cn|zh)/', handler=MobileHome, name='MobileHome'),
]),],
debug=True)
```

my webhome class

```
class WebHome(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, language='en'):
    buf = 'home for %s' % (language,)
    self.response.write(buf)
```

Comment: I cannot understand why you use the same name (like WebHome) for different routes. The name can be used to build an uri. Maybe this the reason for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`webapp2.Route` uses `<` and `>`, not parentheses.  Also, choose only one Route for the `name` parameter if they all use the same `handler`:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([routes.DomainRoute(r'<:(localhost|mysite\.com|www\.mysite\.com)>', [
    webapp2.Route('/', handler=WebHome),
    webapp2.Route('/<language:en|bm|my|cn|zh>', handler=WebHome),
    webapp2.Route('/<language:en|bm|my|cn|zh>/', handler=WebHome, name='WebHome'),
]),

routes.DomainRoute(r'<:(m2.mysite.com|m.mysite.com)>', [
    webapp2.Route('/', handler=MobileHome),
    webapp2.Route('/<language:en|bm|my|cn|zh>', handler=MobileHome),
    webapp2.Route('/<language:en|bm|my|cn|zh>/', handler=MobileHome, name='MobileHome'),
]),], debug=True)
```